# Shimano model number abbreviations

Tags: shimano, terminology

Shimano uses abbreviations in their model numbers. For example, the Shimano Deore Hollowtech II MTB Crankset 3x10-speed has model number [FC-M6000-3](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/deore-m6000/FC-M6000-3.html). Is there a table somewhere that defines all the abbreviations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shimano publishes archived Portable Document Format (PDF) documents on their website at:

https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/archive

For example, the 2019-2020 specification is at:

https://productinfo.shimano.com/download/?path=pdfs/archive/2019-2020_Specifications_v034_en.pdf

Early in the document there is a table of word definitions. The following is the list of word definitions for 2019-2020:

- BB - Bottom bracket
- BC - Brake cable
- BCC - Battery cable
- BCR - Battery charger
- BH - Disc brake hose
- BL - Brake lever
- BM - battery mount
- BR - Brake caliper
- BTC - Battery case
- BTH - Battery holder
- BTR - Battery
- CB - Coaster brake
- CD - Chain device
- CG - Chain guard
- CJ - Cassette joint
- CN - Chain
- CP - Spoke protector
- CR - Chainring
- CS - Cassette sprocket
- CT - Chain tensioner
- DH - Hub dynamo
- DU - Drive unit
- EC - Battery charger
- EW - Electric wire
- EWC - Cord cover
- EWEX - DI2 adapter
- EWW - Wireless unit
- FC - Front chainwheel Crankarm
- FD - Front derailleur
- FH - Freehub
- GM - Grommet
- HB - Front hub
- HP - Head parts
- HRB - Hub roller brake
- I-SPEC - Integration mounting system of brake and shifting lever
- ID - CI-DECK
- JC - Junction
- LP - Light
- MF - Multiple freewheel
- MU - Motor unit
- O.L.D. - Over Locknut Dimension
- OT - Outer casing
- P.C.D. - Pitch Circle Diameter
- PCE - PC Linkage device
- PD - Pedal
- PM - Power modulator
- QR - Quick release
- RD - Rear derailleur
- RT - Disc brake rotor
- RTAD - Disc brake rotor adapter
- SB - REVOSHIFT shifter integrated with brake lever
- SC - Cycle computer System information display
- SF - Single freewheel
- SG - Internal geared hub
- SL - Shifting lever
- SPD - Shimano pedaling dynamics
- SPD-SL - Shimano pedaling dynamics-SL
- ST - Dual control lever/shifting lever integrated with brake lever
- SW - Switch unit
- WH - Wheel

Comment: Is there an overview what the terms "Deore", "XT" etc. mean and what the differences between these product families are?

Comment: @Erlkoenig See argenti’s answer, but basically you get more quality and more performance as you go up the hierarchy. Obviously each level costs more and more.

Answer (score 3):

You can see an overview of the whole Shimano range, including the hierarchy of groupset series in the [line-up chart](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc). You can also drill down into each groupset and see which components are intended to be combined together.

Basically the mountain bike series all start with M and go from M2xxx Acera to M9xxx XTR. Road groups start with R and go from R2xxx Claris to R9xxx Dura Ace. The higher the number the better the groupset. Note that some adjacent ranges of numbers now are grouped under the same grouset name. E.g. the 'Deore' range includes M6100 12 speed, M5100 11 speed and M4100 10 speed. Trekking, gravel and urban ranges follow the same sort of scheme. Below all of that are the Tourney ranges which have a much less structured numbering scheme.

The Wikipedia page for Shimano includes tables of the current and past [mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano#Mountain_bike_groupsets) and [road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano#Road_groupsets) groupsets which also shows the hierarchy and how the groupsets names and number ranges have evolved.